# Color Highlight Laravel Blade Not Working In VS Code

Tags: html, laravel, visual-studio-code

I have a problem to configure file Laravel Blade in visual studio code. Why format color highlight tag HTML different? How to configure the color with the same color? I use extension [Laravel Blade Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade). There is no problem with syntax, but why is syntax color different? anyone please help.

[image]

This below is my setting VS Code:

1. Blade configuration is **OK** to Enable
   [image]
2. full setting in file json

   ```
   {
   "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
   "editor.wordWrap": "on",
   "explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,
   "[html]": {
       "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
   },
   "[json]": {
       "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
   },
   "window.zoomLevel": 0,
   "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
   "[scss]": {
       "editor.defaultFormatter": "sibiraj-s.vscode-scss-formatter"
   },
   "sync.autoUpload": false,
   "sync.autoDownload": false,
   "sync.quietSync": false,
   "sync.forceDownload": false,
   "sync.forceUpload": false,
   "editor.fontSize": 12,
   "debug.console.fontSize": 12,
   "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
   "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes": false,
   "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedFunctions": false,
   "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedConstants": false,
   "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedClassConstants": false,
   "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods": false,
   "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedProperties": false,
   "intelephense.telemetry.enabled": false,
   "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
   "blade.format.enable": true,
   "beautify.language": {
       "js": {
         "type": ["javascript", "json"],
         "filename": [".jshintrc", ".jsbeautifyrc"]
         // "ext": ["js", "json"]
       },
       "css": ["css", "scss"],
       "html": ["htm", "html", "blade"]
     },
   "[blade]": {
       "editor.defaultFormatter": "onecentlin.laravel-blade",
       "editor.formatOnSave": true
   },
   "update.mode": "manual",
   "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
   "emmet.includeLanguages": {
   "[blade]":"html"
   },
   "editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom",
   "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"
   }
   ```

   [Edited based on comment @ettdro]  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184308/color-highlight-laravel-blade-not-working-in-vs-code?noredirect=1#comment110000980_62184308)
3. Sure,I have setting configuration file in bottom bar to Laravel Blade. But still no changes.
   [image]

[SOLVED]

In a way that might not be recommended, I **reinstalled** the VS Code along with removing all of its settings. And then formatting is working perfectly.

Comment: Have you just tried reinstall the extension?

Comment: yes, i have tried it.. but still same, no changes. 
I was really confused to format it, @ettdro.

Comment: If you check on the right bottom of your file on VSCode in the bottom bar where you can see the line and column your cursor's at, there is supposed to be the highlighting you can choose from there. Make sure you choose "Laravel Blade" as syntax highlighting.

Comment: I have already set it to the "Laravel Blade". But still no change the syntax color highlight. @ettdro

Comment: It is maybe some settings where you say to use HTML for Blade files. In your settings.json I see places where HTML is used for blade, though, Blade is some php files. Try using PHP instead in that setting?

Comment: case close. Finally, I reinstalled my VS Code to remove all the setting, and then working perfectly.. thanks @ettdro for your attention with my problem.

Comment: Awesome! Aometimes its better to reinstall everything haha

Answer (score 3):

Disable "Laravel 5 Snippets".
Enable "Laravel Blade Snippets".
"Laravel Blade" → "Blade".

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: I stumbled upon this question looking for a solution to the same issue.
I've installed extension ID: onecentlin.laravel-blade  "Laravel Blade Snippets" by "onecentlin" and now it's working