# Visual Studio Code - Blade format all white text?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

Recently my visual studio code workspaces text for blade files are all white like this.
[image]

Does anyone know why and how to bring back colors again?

Comment: Which extension are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Install the laravel blade snippets extension pack in the VScode marketplace that is located in your left navbar.

This include blade snippets and blade highlights which will result in your "colored" text

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you install some extensions like "Laravel Blade snippets"
, and if it does not work there is a question:

[Color Highlight Laravel Blade Not Working In VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184308/color-highlight-laravel-blade-not-working-in-vs-code)

That maybe can help you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had installed [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client), which was overwriting the styles. Disabling PHP Language Features restored .blade.php colors.

If we read the Intelephense details it says:

> Quick Start
>
> 1. Disable the built-in VSCode PHP Language Features.
>
> **Go to Extensions. Search for @builtin php Disable PHP Language
> Features.** Leave PHP Language Basics enabled for syntax highlighting.
> Note that other (3rd party) PHP extensions which provide similar
> functionality should also be disabled for best results.
>
> Add glob patterns for non standard php file extensions to the
> files.associations setting.
>
> For example: "files.associations": { "*.module": "php" }.
>
> Optionally purchase and enter your licence key by opening the command
> pallete -- ctrl + shift + p -- and searching for Enter licence key.
>
> Further configuration options are available in the intelephense
> section of settings.